# Appending tuples to lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

What's the proper syntax for adding a recomposed tuple to a list?

For example, if I had two lists:

```
>>> a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
>>> b = [(0,0)]
```

Then I would expect the following to work:

```
>>> b.append((a[0][0],a[0,2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Furthermore, when it informs me that indices must be integers, how come this works?

```
>>> b.append((7,7))
>>> b
[(0, 0), (7, 7)]
```

Comment: Can you clarify your edit to say that that typo was the underlying problem? Currently it's not clear if your edit is clarifying the question or identifying the root cause of the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have try to do this:

```
(a[0][0],a[0,2])
           ^^^
```

this is like doing:

```
(a[0][0],a[(0,2)])
```

which like the error said : list indices must be integers, not tuple

if i'm not mistaken, i think you wanted to do:

```
b.append((a[0][0],a[0][2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
b.append((a[0][0],a[0,2]))
                     ^
```

You try to use the nonexistent tuple index `[0, 2]` when you mean `[0][2]`

Answer (score 1):

The *indices* must be integers.  It's just a typo where you have `a[0,2]` instead of `a[0][2]`.  The `[0,2]` is an attempt to *index* by tuple.

Answer (score 0):

a[0,2] is your problem.

It's not complaining about the append, it's telling you that [0,2] cannot be used as an index for the list a.